# Loop on each level of a factor

Tags: r, loops, levels

What finally worked was:

```
        a <- cast(we, year ~ region, mean, value='response')
```

Although, I only have 1 observation per region and site, so mean is just a workaround. I couldn't get c to work as a function.

- Output for suggested answer (by Justin)

  ```
      > DT
      > response year
      > 1:      15 2000
      > 2:       6 2000
      > 3:      23 2000
      > 4:      23 2000
       ---             
      > 794:       3 2010
      > 795:       5 2010
      > 796:       1 2010
  ```
- Update: desired output should look like:

  ```
     > Year   x1  x2  x3   x4
     > 2000   4   5   16   22
     > 2001   6   11   2   18
     > 2002   1   0   21   10
     > ...
  ```

I am struggling to find a way to transpose my data based on factor levels. I have data with 2 columns, a factor and a response. I have many rows for each factor, so I want to transpose the table such that each factor is on one row, with the different responses as a column in that row. I cannot seem to subset within a loop based on levels of that factor. I would appreciate any insight.

example of data:

```
          > response    year
          > 5           2001
          > 10          2001
          > 8           2001
          > 1           2002
          > 7           2010

  > levels(data$year)
  [1] "2000" "2001" "2002" "2003" "2004" "2005" ...
  w <- matrix(0,54,15)

  for(i in 1:levels(data$year)){
    w[i] <- levels(data$year)==i
  }
```

This syntax is obviously not correct, but it is the idea of what I'm trying to accomplish.

Thank you.

Comment: Can you include your desired output.  I don't fully understand what you're trying to do.

Comment: Yes, I want a row for each year (factor level) with the responses in that row: I'll provide example above in question.

Comment: It's still unclear even though you have an example because there's no way of knowing what goes in what column. What are x1, x2, etc.? In a row, are the additional columns the actual response and the entries the counts of the response in that cell? Or, are the x1, etc. columns an additional factor besides year and the responses are just the actual response.

Comment: Please refrain from changing your question and instead add to it for clarification.

Answer (score 1):

Using the `data.table` package this is trivial:

```
library(data.table)
DT <- data.table(data)
DT[, as.list(value), by=year]
```

However, this will fall apart if you have different numbers of observations per year.  Instead:

```
DT[, list(values = list(value)), by=year]
```

Or using base R:

```
tapply(data$value, data$year, c)
```

Comment: That seemed to work, but it doesn't give me a consolidated data table it seems to give me a split of rows by year as opposed to columns with values by year all in one row. Maybe I'm missing a step? I'll post the output above.

Comment: The first version will give you columns.  But that plan can only work if you have an equal number of samples in each year.  Otherwise, the list like version returned from `tapply` will be a much better option.

Comment: As an alternative to `tapply` you can also use `with(data, split(value, year))`

Comment: Yes, I think the tapply will work, but it puts all values into one list. I guess I can just separate based on columns into individual columns. I'll work with that. Thank you.

Comment: As a follow up to Jilber, is it possible to stack the split output into a single data frame?

Comment: `as.data.frame(with(data, split(value, year)))` but again, if you have different numbers of observations this won't work.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another way, using `aggregate`:

```
> set.seed(1)
> data <- data.frame(year = rep(2000:2010, each=10), value = sample(3:30, 110, TRUE))
> aggregate(value~year, data=data, FUN=c)
   year value.1 value.2 value.3 value.4 value.5 value.6 value.7 value.8 value.9 value.10
1  2000      10      13      19      28       8      28      29      21      20        4
2  2001       8       7      22      13      24      16      23      30      13       24
3  2002      29       8      21       6      10      13       3      13      27       12
4  2003      16      19      16       8      26      21      25       6      23       14
5  2004      25      21      24      18      17      25       3      16      23       22
6  2005      16      27      15       9       4       5      11      17      21       14
7  2006      28      11      15      12      21      10      16      24       5       27
8  2007      12      26      12      12      16      27      27      13      24       29
9  2008      15      22      14      12      24       8      22       6       9        7
10 2009       9       4      20      27      24      25      15      14      25       19
11 2010      21      12      10      30      20       8       6      16      28       19
```

Comment: That looks like it might be what's being asked for.

Comment: This looks exactly like what I need, but for some reason I am getting the following error: Error in get(as.character(FUN), mode = "function", envir = envir) : 
  object 'FUN' of mode 'function' was not found

Comment: You are getting this error because (maybe) you have an object named `c` in your environment, so you have overwritten the function `c` and that's why the error is appearing. There are two solutions: 1) delete the `c` object you have in your session or 2) provide the environment where the `c` function is contained: `aggregate(value~year, data=data, FUN=base::c)` I prefer the last one :D

Comment: Ah, yes. However, I stil get a resulting data frame with 2 columns - one with my values as a comma separated list. It doesn't look like your output above.

Comment: I used simulated values, so on my example the code runs ok, maybe your data dont look like the ones in my example. Also note that the quality of the answers depends on the quality of your question, if none of the answers solve your problem then try to take one moment and write a good question with samle of data, what have you tried and the expected result, please be clear.

Comment: I appreciate the suggestions, and I thought my question was clear. I have tried the suggestions and replied accordingly - none have worked. I will think about how I could have improved this interaction.

Answer (score 0):

If I had a different number of responses per year, I would probably come at this problem by first making a new variable to represent the response in each year and then casting that dataset out using `dcast`.  By default `dcast` fills in missing values with `NA`, although you can change that if needed.

```
set.seed(1)
data = data.frame(year = c(rep(2000:2010, each=10), 2011), value = sample(3:30, 111, TRUE))

require(reshape2)
require(plyr)
# Create a new variable representing the number of responses per year and add to dataset
dat2 = ddply(data, .(year), transform, 
              response = interaction("x", 1:length(value), sep = ""))

dcast(dat2, year ~ response, value.var = "value")
```

Comment: I think the variable number of responses per year is a problem for this.

Comment: My example does have a variable number of responses per year.  That's the reason I put this up.  I could see a problem if you have, say, responses 1-4 in one year and responses 2-5 in another year.  I'm not sure how you'd deal with that.